# How to know priority of a particular built-in directive in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am learning AngularJs,in which I am studying **Directives**, **Directive Object** . I am referring [angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) and **ng-book** in which

[image]

In this it is mentioned that

> Most directives omit this option, in which case it defaults
>   to 0 and **ngRepeat has the highest priority of any built-in directive. It is always invoked before other directives on the same element**.

but still it is not clearly mentioned about what exact priority (number) a particular  **built-in Directive** such as **ng-model** or **ng-repeat** or **ng-bind** possess.
so please let me know is there any reference that clearly describes priorities about built-in directives.

Comment: @ Pierre will you please give some example that shows priority of built-in directive more than zero?.